# React Redux : TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, redux, axios

I am trying to create Profile page to show specifc data for single user .
the problem when I want to get the profile state using connect it returns to null !!
the profile state should have the payload from the backend

in Profile.js

```
const Profile = ({ getProfileById, profile: { profile }, auth, match }) => {
  console.log(profile);
  useEffect(() => {
    
    getProfileById(match.params.id);
  }, [getProfileById, match.params.id]);
console.log(profile);
    return (
        <Fragment>
            {profile === null ? (<Spinner/>) : (<Fragment>
                <Link to="/Profiles" className="btn btn-light">
            Back To Profiles
          </Link>
                 </Fragment>)}

                 {auth.isAuthenticated &&
                auth.loading === false &&
                auth.user._id === profile.user._id && (
              <Link to="/edit-profile" className="btn btn-dark">
                Edit Profile
              </Link>
            )}

          <div className="profile-grid my-1">
            
// when I pass profile as prop returns null
         <ProfileTop profile={profile} />
             </div>
        </Fragment>
    )
}

Profile.propTypes = {
getProfileById : PropTypes.func.isRequired,
profile : PropTypes.object.isRequired,
auth : PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  profile: state.profile,
  auth: state.auth
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps,{getProfileById}) (Profile)
```

in ProfileTop.js

```
const ProfileTop = ({profile : {
// Here showes the error ×
//TypeError: Cannot read property 'company' of null
    company,
    location,
    social,
    user : {name,avatar}
}}) => {
    return (
        <div className="profile-top bg-primary p-2">
        <img
          src={avatar}
          alt=""
          className="round-img"
        />
      </div>
    )
}

ProfileTop.propTypes = {
    profile : PropTypes.object.isRequired,

}

export default ProfileTop
```

note : Before I add The functionality when I see redux dev tools the profile does not equal null

here's getProfileById Action ..

```
export const getProfileById = userId => async dispatch => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(`/profile/user/${userId}`);
  
      dispatch({
        type: GET_PROFILE,
        payload: res.data
      });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      dispatch({
        type: PROFILE_ERROR,
        payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status }
      });
    }
  };
```

the initial State ..

```
const initialState = {

    profile : null,
    profiles : [],
    repos : [],
    loading : true ,
    error : {}
}
```

the GET_PROFILE Reducer

```
case GET_PROFILE : 
return {...state,
    profile : payload,
    loading : false
}
```

Comment: initialState = null, is this in the component or in the store?

Comment: In the Store ..

Comment: have you checked if axios is working correctly?

Comment: I think the problem from axios I think It doesn't send the request to the api I checked network tools on chrome , I don't know what the wrong I did!!!

Answer (score 1):

Ooopes guys I solved the problem It was because the closing tag of the Fragment I did not notice that  today's lesson don't code when you have stayed up for more then 20 hours ..

```
return (
        <Fragment>
            {profile === null ? (<Spinner/>) : (<Fragment>
                <Link to="/Profiles" className="btn btn-light">
            Back To Profiles
          </Link>
// here I close the fragment normally profile will returns null
// I should close it right after the closing div
                 </Fragment>)}

                 {auth.isAuthenticated &&
                auth.loading === false &&
                auth.user._id === profile.user._id && (
              <Link to="/edit-profile" className="btn btn-dark">
                Edit Profile
              </Link>
            )}

          <div className="profile-grid my-1">
            

         <ProfileTop profile={profile} />
             </div>
        </Fragment>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Profile must get the data from action.payload and not from payload.

```
return {
    ...state,
    profile : action.payload,
    loading : false
}
```

Comment: I destructured above with const { type,payload} = action;